# Is there a way to spoof a browser's resolution / return retina images?

Tags: css, browser, resolution, retina-display

I'm curious how CSS makes determinations about Media Query conditions! [This great CSS-Tricks post](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/) shows some of the conditions like device-pixel-ratio and min-resolution.

Is there a way to have a browser spoof this / pretend to have higher resolution? It would be ideal to do this without touching the code on the site in question (eg. maybe affecting an iFrame to test what happens to cnn.com when viewed on a retina device).

Would be so handy for debugging / testing without devices.

Comment: check http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/ and http://designshack.net/articles/graphics/designing-on-a-retina-screen-my-thoughts-on-the-retina-macbook-pro/

Comment: The only place where I've seen this is with the ios simulator that comes with xcode. It runs iphone and ipad retina simulators. They come with Safari installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started doing this in a different way. It's kinda hacky, but I like it!

```
@media 
(height: 999px),
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
(min-resolution: 192dpi) {
     .wrapper {background:url(img/image@2x.jpg);}
}
```

I specify a specific height at which to also trigger the media query. For production I remove that one condition of the media query.